# How exactly do multiple people work on a project together?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have been working solo on a project for quite some time and am reaching the point where having another developer on the project would be helpful. I am a fresh college graduate, so I have only programmed alone and have never had the need to use any version control software.

Since I will be using `Visual Studio`, I would like to use [`Team Foundation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) for version control.

What does a life cycle of a piece of software look like using `Team Foundation`?

- Where is the code stored
- When building, where is it building?
- How does branching/merging work?

How are errors handled? For instance, if I commit a broken piece of code?

- Will the other developer still be able to function?
- Will it build using a previous version of the broken file?

EDIT: This may be a naive question, but is the project solution file also backed up as part of version control? As far as I know, this file is responsible for knowing what other files are required for a project and opening them in the solution explorer. Does it serve any other purpose? How do other developers get this file and what happens when a new file is added to the project?

Any additional information would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with a team of about a dozen coders.

We use Visual Studio 2010 and [**SVN**](http://subversion.tigris.org/) with [**TortoiseSVN**](http://tortoisesvn.net) as client for source control. We also use [**AnkhSVN**](http://ankhsvn.net) to let us easily access SVN from within Solution Explorer in VS.

We maintain our code repositories on our network, and use [**CruiseControl**](http://cruisecontrol.net) for continuous integration to rebuild separate projects following commits. For hotfixes or major releases, we branch our code off trunk; individual developers will branch separate tasks off to their own branches and maintain them should they persist over multiple releases (e.g. merging code changes promoted to production that happen to overlap with stuff they're working on).

There are certain projects (mainly libraries and WCF clients) we have which are shared with other departments that we reference as [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) in some of our projects.

If someone breaks a build, CruiseControl periodically sends an email to our group informing them of the broken project and who last committed changes.

In general as long as you keep cognizant of changes affecting you, and changes of yours affecting everyone else, you can pretty well roll with the punches and maintain a fairly agile and flexible setup.